# Facebook Release Key not working with updates?

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-android-sdk

I have created simple application. Where i am doing login with facebook sdk.
For this I am generating release key.

My Issue is: When I generate it first time it works fine but when i update my apk in play store before this it automatically generate new key.
And if i placed new key in facebook developer setting then all old app stop working.

And if i won't change new key has in developer setting then new app won't work.

So I want that how can i generate key which will work with all new and old apk?

Please let me know nothing is working for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can define more than one key hash in the "Key Hashes" field of your application in your apps settings page.